# Go process prematurely dies when capturing SIGINT and SIGTERM

Tags: go, signals

I have a fairly straight forward signal handling and cleanup process:

```
func signalHandler(shutdown func() error) {
    // Make signal channel and register notifiers for Interupt and Terminate
    sigchan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigchan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    // Block until we receive a signal on the channel
    <-sigchan

    // Shutdown now that we've received the signal
    if err := shutdown(); err != nil {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("shutdown error: %s", err.Error())
        log.Fatal(msg)
    }

    log.Println("shutdown procedure complete") 

    // Make a clean exit
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

This hander is running a go routine from the server:

```
func (s *Server) Run() error {
    go signalHandler(s.Shutdown) 
    ...

    <-s.done // block until done 
    log.Println("done running!") 
    return nil 
}

func (s *Server) Shutdown() error {
    s.done <- true 
    log.Println("all done here!") 
    return nil 
}
```

The problem is that the process exits before the "all done here!" can be printed to the log, and sometimes "done running" prints and other times it doesn't. It seems like there is an `os.Exit()` call somewhere else (possibly in one of the libraries I'm using?). I do need to clean up connections and delete temporary files etc, and they're not getting cleaned up properly.

Does anyone know how I diagnose where the process is exiting?

**Update**: I'm also not seeing "shutdown procedure complete" with the addition of that log statement. It appears that the process is terminating before this function is over.

Comment: Is `s.done` a buffered channel?

Comment: `shutdown` doesn't call `*Server.Shutdown()`, it is `*Server.Shutdown()` - I'm passing it directly into the signalHandler in the `*Server.Run()` method.

Comment: I've tried both buffered and unbuffered - same effect.

Comment: There is no synchronization to wait for Run to complete, so that isn't guaranteed to ever print, but "all done here" should be written to the log. Is the log output the standard unbuffered stderr?

Comment: What's the content of `main()`? Does it call `*Server.Run()` as its last operation?

Comment: Yes `main()` calls `server.Run()` and checks if there is an error then logs it -- that's the last thing it does.

Comment: I haven't messed with the `log` library in anyway, and I'm seeing print lines, so I'm assuming everything is set up with stdout -- no error is returned from shutdown at the moment, so I don't think I'm missing anything from `log.Fatal`.

Comment: And so we're on the same page, I'm issuing the interrupt with CTRL+C - I appreciate you guys thinking about this!

Comment: As soon as `Run()` returns, `main()` returns, and when `main()` returns, the program exits.

Comment: I generally put signal handling in `main()` itself, rather than in any goroutine, to ensure that `main()` does not return before I'm done handling post-signal shutdown procedures.

Comment: @Adrian - ah, I see what you mean - ok, that definitely makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154375/discussion-between-bbengfort-and-adrian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the call to `Run()` is the last real op in `main()`. As soon as `Run()` returns, `main()` returns, and when `main()` returns, the program exits. I generally put signal handling in `main()` itself, rather than in any goroutine, to ensure that `main()` does not return before I'm done handling post-signal shutdown procedures.

(From the comments, reposting as an answer now that it's sorted.)